# Inserting into an ordered, doubly linked list

Tags: c, list

I have written a function that inserts an element into a doubly linked list, maintaining the list in order (by field `nr_indeksu` of the element struct). It runs correctly on some inputs, but given this data ...

```
11111 Aleks 3
22222 Kuba 5
33333 Filip 84
44444 Szymon 2
55555 asdasd 5
66666 qweqwe 2
```

... it puts the first record (11111 Aleks 3) at the last position, instead of at the first position. Here is the function:

```
void Insert(para **head, para **tail, para wczytywanie) // przerabianie     funkcji insert
{
    para *temp = (struct para*)malloc(sizeof(struct para));
    temp->nr_indeksu = wczytywanie.nr_indeksu;
    strcpy(temp->nazwisko, wczytywanie.nazwisko);
    temp->ocena = wczytywanie.ocena;

    if (isEmpty(*head))
        InsertAsFirstElement(head, tail, wczytywanie);
    else if (head == tail) // jezeli jest dopiero jeden element w liscie
    {
        if ((*head)->nr_indeksu < temp->nr_indeksu)
        {
            InsertAsLastElement(head, tail, wczytywanie);
        }
        else
        {
            // dodanie przed headem
            (*head)->prev = temp;
            temp->next = *head;
            temp->prev = NULL;
            *head = temp;
        }
    }
    else // jak znajdziemy odpowiedni element wstawiamy za nim
    { 
        struct para *search = *head;
        while (search->next != NULL && search->nr_indeksu < temp->nr_indeksu)
            search = search->next;
        if (search->prev == NULL)
        {
            (*head)->prev = temp;
            temp->next = *head;
            temp->prev = NULL;
            *head = temp;
        }
        else if (search->next == NULL)
        {
            if (search->nr_indeksu < temp->nr_indeksu)
            {
                temp->next = *tail;
                temp->prev = (*tail)->prev;
                (*tail)->prev->next = temp;
                (*tail)->prev = temp;

            }   //przed tailem
            else
            {
                temp->prev = *tail;
                (*tail)->next = temp;
                temp->next = NULL;
                (*tail) = temp;
            }
                //za tailem
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = search;
            temp->prev = search->prev;
            search->prev->next = temp;
            search->prev = temp;
            //przed searchem
        }
    }
}
```

What is my error?

Comment: always use a sentry (sentinel) node when writing linked lists. see for example http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Comment: The parameter to function `Insert()` accepts a pointer to a pointer. In your code you compare if `head == tail`. They will never be equal as they are 2 independent variables. You meant to compare `*head == *tail` to check if they are both pointing to the same memory location. Because of this bug, it goes to the `else` clause where `search->next` will be NULL because there's only 1 element and `search->prev` will also be null. Your code then assumes the `temp` should be inserted.

Comment: As @alvits said.  Moreover, there's no particular reason why a single-element list needs to be a different case than inserting at the head or tail of a longer list.

Comment: In fact, even inserting into an *empty* list doesn't need to be distinguished as its own case.  Done right, it ends up handled properly by the code that handles insertion at the beginning of the list and the code that handles insertion at the tail of the list (both).  Your function is around three times as long as it needs to be, even before counting the three auxiliary functions it uses.